# CV2 No puedo calibrar correctamente las camaras stereo

Tags: python, opencv

me encuentro en un punto sin salida. Estoy intentando calibrar 2 camaras para poder aproximar la profundidad hacia un objeto.Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import glob, os

img_globdir="/home/admin/CALIBRATION"

#Encontrar Puntos del Tablero de Ajedrez

chessboardSize = (9,6)
frameSize = (320,240)



# termination criteria
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)


# Creamos puntos de imagenes en 3 dimensiones
objp = np.zeros((chessboardSize[0] * chessboardSize[1], 3), np.float32)

#Multiplicamos al final del mgrid por el tamaño de los cuadrados del tablero (22mm para este caso)

objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:chessboardSize[0],0:chessboardSize[1]].T.reshape(-1,2)*22

#Se devolera un mapa de puntos en la unidad entregada anteriormente, en este caso en milimetros.

# Arreglos para almacenar los valores.
objpoints = [] # Puntos 3d del mundo real
imgpointsL = [] # puntos 2d IZQ
imgpointsR = [] # puntos 2d DER


imagesLeft = sorted(glob.glob(f'{img_globdir}/FOTO_IZQ/*.png'))
imagesRight = sorted(glob.glob(f'{img_globdir}/FOTO_DER/*.png'))
name_map=os.path.basename(imagesRight[0])[:16]
for imgLeft, imgRight in zip(imagesLeft, imagesRight):

    imgL = cv.imread(imgLeft)
    imgR = cv.imread(imgRight)
    grayL = cv.cvtColor(imgL, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
    grayR = cv.cvtColor(imgR, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    retL, cornersL = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayL, chessboardSize, None)
    retR, cornersR = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayR, chessboardSize, None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if retL and retR == True:

        objpoints.append(objp)

        cornersL = cv.cornerSubPix(grayL, cornersL, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpointsL.append(cornersL)

        cornersR = cv.cornerSubPix(grayR, cornersR, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpointsR.append(cornersR)

        # Draw and display the corners
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(imgL, chessboardSize, cornersL, retL)
        cv.imshow('img left', imgL)
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(imgR, chessboardSize, cornersR, retR)
        cv.imshow('img right', imgR)
        cv.waitKey(0)
 


cv.destroyAllWindows()




#Calibracion

retL, cameraMatrixL, distL, rvecsL, tvecsL = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpointsL, frameSize, None, None)
heightL, widthL, channelsL = imgL.shape
newCameraMatrixL, roi_L = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrixL, distL, (widthL, heightL), 1, (widthL, heightL))

retR, cameraMatrixR, distR, rvecsR, tvecsR = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpointsR, frameSize, None, None)
heightR, widthR, channelsR = imgR.shape
newCameraMatrixR, roi_R = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrixR, distR, (widthR, heightR), 1, (widthR, heightR))



#Calibracion Stereo

flags = 0
flags |= cv.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC

criteria_stereo= (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)


retStereo, newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, rot, trans, essentialMatrix, fundamentalMatrix = cv.stereoCalibrate(objpoints, imgpointsL, imgpointsR, newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, grayL.shape[::-1], criteria_stereo, flags)

#Rectificacion Stereo

rectifyScale= 1
rectL, rectR, projMatrixL, projMatrixR, Q, roi_L, roi_R= cv.stereoRectify(newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, grayL.shape[::-1], rot, trans, rectifyScale,(0,0))

stereoMapL = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(newCameraMatrixL, distL, rectL, projMatrixL, grayL.shape[::-1], cv.CV_16SC2)
stereoMapR = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(newCameraMatrixR, distR, rectR, projMatrixR, grayR.shape[::-1], cv.CV_16SC2)


if not os.path.exists(f'{img_globdir}/MAPAS'):
    os.mkdir(f'{img_globdir}/MAPAS')
cv_file = cv.FileStorage(f'{img_globdir}/MAPAS/{name_map}.xml', cv.FILE_STORAGE_WRITE)

cv_file.write('stereoMapL_x',stereoMapL[0])
cv_file.write('stereoMapL_y',stereoMapL[1])
cv_file.write('stereoMapR_x',stereoMapR[0])
cv_file.write('stereoMapR_y',stereoMapR[1])
cv_file.write('f',np.round(Q[2][3]))
cv_file.write('b',np.round(Q[3][2]))

cv_file.release()
```

Mi problema surge que, al calibrar las camaras, obtengo una Matriz Q. De esta misma saco tanto la distancia focal 'f' como la separacion entre camaras 'b' dado que en otro foro lei que es mejor extraerla de la matriz antes que codificarla con los valores reales.

Inicialmente use 2 camaras Logitech c922, y 'b' siempre daba 0. Probe con mayor separacion entre camaras, menor, con otras imagenes, incluso lei que podia afectar la diferencia de tiempo entre cada imagen, por lo cual le dedique un hilo a cada obtencion de fotograma.

Al no encontrar respuesta, opte por comprar una camara stereo para robotica, el modelo es ELP-1080P2CAM-l28 (http://www.elpcctv.com/2mp-ar0330-uvc-otg-binocular-stereo-vision-camera-module-with-28mm-lens-for-ar-augmented-reality-p-252.html)

Al probarlo toda la mañana, me encuentro en la misma situacion. Siempre b=0.

Probe obviar en todos los casos esto e intentar codificar los valores directamente sobre el codigo de python, utilizo el mapa de disparidad generado y rectifico las imagenes, posteriormente intento pero al realizar la triangulacion con la formula

```
Z = (b * f)/Disparidad
```

Los valores de profundidad son cualquier cosa.

Dejo mis imagenes obtenidas por esta ultima camara en los siguientes enlaces.

```
https://ibb.co/NWR9LWw
https://ibb.co/8zZtFd8
https://ibb.co/Syr1Ngq
https://ibb.co/CwhB4XX
https://ibb.co/hgbQWs7
https://ibb.co/6D9ShPQ
https://ibb.co/QDfqW11
```

Si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal, se lo agradeceria profundamente. Muchas gracias

Comment: La pagina me restringia poner tantos links, aca dejo los demas:
https://ibb.co/PDdhSgy
https://ibb.co/sjstVrX
https://ibb.co/FJH9cqn
https://ibb.co/2jFJcCS
https://ibb.co/BVCHcw7
https://ibb.co/HPTyfGM
https://ibb.co/FxjkSHN